# How to make pandas.read_sql consistently return `NULL` values as `NaN`?

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say I have a table in a database containing data as follows:

```
date                    value
2023-10-01 08:00:00      88.3
2023-10-02 08:00:00      75.4
2023-10-03 08:00:00      NULL
```

When I read data from this table using `pandas.read_sql()`, if I read all of the above table, the resulting data frame will have 'value' as a float column with the `NULL` value as a `NaN` value.
However, if I read from the table with for example a `WHERE date BETWEEN '2023-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2023-10-04 00:00:00'` condition so that the result only contains the third row, 'value' instead becomes an object column with a `None` value. This causes me trouble in a test where I have to expect either `NaN` or `None` values.
Is there a way to force `pandas.read_sql()` to consistently return a data frame with 'value' as a float column (with `NaN`values)?

Comment: Easiest option might be: `df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: Which Pandas version? `None` or rather `NA` is the *correct* value but Pandas is a "bit" inconsistent on this, from version to version. NumPy had no notion of Null so Pandas ended up with NaT, NaN and lately None is some cases. `NaN` is exactly wrong from a relational and float perspective because it's a very specific floating point value, while NULL means we don't know what the value is. We don't even know if the value is missing or isn't applicable

Comment: @Panagiotis here this is `'NULL'`, so most likely a string

Comment: @mozway is it? We don't know, we have no test data. If it *is* though ... Pandas 2.0 was released with a known (and acknowledged) bug that inserted NaN to the database as the string `"NaN"`. That's why I asked what version is used. There have been similar breaking changes in minor versions since

Comment: BTW expect things to standardize on `NA`/pd.NA as [Pandas migrates to PyArrow](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/pyarrow.html). One of the main goals is `Missing data support (NA) for all data types` with examples showing `<NA>` even in numeric columns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for now it is Pandas 2.1.1 in my case. I wanted to make it behave consistently with having a float column, but your remark about pd.NA sounds important to keep in mind for when I suppose I eventually want to use a PyArrow backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can enforce data type for specific columns through `dtype` parameter.
Sample query:

```
from sqlite3 import connect

conn = connect(':memory:')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0, '10/11/12'], [1, '12/11/10'], [None, '12/11/10']],
                  columns=['value', 'date'])

df.to_sql(name='test_data', con=conn)
print(pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM test_data where value is NULL',
                  conn, dtype={'value': float}))
```

---

```
   index  value      date
0      2    NaN  12/11/10
```